# Working with Markdown properly and securely

Tags: javascript, jquery, markdown

Which is the best approach in working with markdown?

- I save the markdown to the database and parse it on load with javascript?
- I parse the markdown to html and then save to the database and load it on the dom unescaped?

The 1st option, I don't have to use unescaped data but it means I have to use javascript to parse a lot of markdown syntax like on a comment thread.

The 2nd option probably gives me performance because I can now just load the data directly to the DOM, but this also means I have to load it unescaped.

So which approach would you recommend or is there any other better approach?

Comment: I would go for the second option, but make sure that the parsing gets rid of things like script tags in the markdown. Consider that having html in the markdown is still valid markdown. You are going to have to remove dangerous content, either before storing or after retrieval, but with the second option you will be doing this only once, not every time.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, I think the second approach is not safe. You can't trust user for submit the correct "html" that rendered by markdown and you should never render user submit data in raw html (no escape), there will be script inject easily. I will choose option 1